# Error:Annotation processor '__gen.AnnotationProcessorWrapper_debug_android_databinding_annotationprocessor_ProcessDataBinding' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger-2, android-databinding

So, I'm trying to build my Android project with Kotlin and add Android DataBinding library into it. In Android Studio 2.2.3 there was no problem with it. But after update to the latest Android Studio version (2.3.0) I got this error when try to run the app.

[image]

Here is my Project's build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.1.0'
    ext.androidGradlePluginVersion = '2.3.0'

    ...

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${androidGradlePluginVersion}"

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

...
```

And here is my App's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    ...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}

dependencies {

    ...
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$androidGradlePluginVersion"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
}
```

Is there something that I have to updated to make Kotlin work with Android DataBinding library? Please help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Based on @Rene answer, I tried to replace **kotlin-android-extensions** with **kotlin-kapt** , But when I tried to sync gradle I got another error.

[image]

[image]

Anyone what's wrong from this error? Thanks

**FIX THAT WORKS:**

Turns out I just need to update some line related with Dagger2 in my gradle. I REMOVE this line below from my Project's build.gradle file.

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

And update the dependencies related Dagger2 in my app's build.gradle file to be like this.

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

I got this settings from this [article](http://www.andevcon.com/news/keddit-part-10-kotlin-dagger-2-dependency-injection)

Here is my build.gradle content that WORKS for me.

Project's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.1.0'
    ext.androidGradlePluginVersion = '2.3.0'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${androidGradlePluginVersion}"

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 2
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '25.2.0'
    retrofitVersion = '2.2.0'
    daggerVersion = '2.7'
    googleServiceVersion = '10.2.0'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.0.6'
    rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    glideVersion = '3.7.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '1.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:${retrofitVersion}"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'

    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-ui:${supportLibVersion}"

    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${constraintLayoutVersion}"

    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.8.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:1.8.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:materialize:1.0.0@aar'


    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${googleServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${googleServiceVersion}"

    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxJavaVersion}"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rxAndroidVersion}"

    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glideVersion}"

    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$androidGradlePluginVersion"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlinVersion"

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Kotlin 1.1 I've had to switch to the newer Kotlin annotation processor.

Apply it like so:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

I've found it first mentioned in the 1.0.6 release at [kotlin-1-0-6-is-here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/12/kotlin-1-0-6-is-here/)

Comment: Hi @Rene thank you so much for you answer, but after trying to apply your suggestion i got another error. you can look the update on my post. thanks

Comment: You can keep other plugins like the extension, kapt does not replace that one.

Comment: Hi @Rene, actually I use Dagger2 also in my project, but since I don't think it's related with the issue, so I don't write it in my question. But turns out commenting all Dagger2 related in my project and app's level build.gradle fix the issue. hmm :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `android-apt` plugin from build script classpath.
2. Use `kapt` instead of `apt`/`annotationProcessor` in your dependency configuration.
3. Add `kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'` to your dependencies because Kotlin + Android Build Plugin 2.3.0 with databinding combo is broken.

What I think happens is that `kapt` is replacing annotation processor and not picking up `annotationProcessor` configurations which is what databinding uses instead of `android-apt` plugin since 2.3.0.

See also: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228983

---

If you didn't use Kotlin:

1. Remove `android-apt` plugin from build script classpath.
2. Use `annotationProcessor` instead of `apt` in your dependency configuration.

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same issue today when upgrading to Kotlin 1.1.

"fixed" it by rolling back to gradle 2.2.3

I wasn't using apt in my project at all, might be related to the databinding library.
I use kapt for realm, butterknife, dagger and databinding.

Comment: Hey there, Since i succeeded to make it work with 2.3.0, maybe you can check my updated answer, I just copy-paste my build.gradle file to the bottom part of my question. Cheers

Comment: Yes, Im using DataBinding.

Comment: okay so, the only difference i see is im using `kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.2.3'`, while you're using the same version as your gradle plugin version. That might actually be it. I'll give it a try and report back tonight